# Laravel file download: file remains an old file while I deleted it and uploaded a replacement

Tags: laravel, file, download

I am trying to have a file downloaded, and it all went well but I wanted to change the file's name. It's essentially a sample document to help people understand how data should be processed. The old name was "Testdocument" which I found confusing, so I renamed it to example, cleared it all out and deleted the old file and replaced it with the new.

However, it is still downloading the old file, with the old data and name while it isn't even present anymore?? How is this possible?

Controller code:

```php
    public function download(){
        $path = public_path('files/Voorbeeld.xlsx');
        return response()->download($path);
    }
```

Download route:

```php
Route::get('/download', 'Datacontroller@download')->name('download');
```

And last but not least the download button

```php
<a href="{{ route('download') }}">Download Sample</a>
```

My project structure (the public folder) for reference:

[image]

As you can see there is no such file as what is being downloaded right now:
[image]

It honestly feels like a weird hallucination to me. If anyone might know the problem then I'd be glad to hear more about a (possible) solution.

Comment: When do you replace file name??

Comment: What do you mean replace? It's the only file in the folder, there shouldn't be any other downloadable file but there is for some reason.